# Why is the header widget not displaying on Google Chrome?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have customized my Wordpress website template and added a header widget. For reference, the website is tuts.iniladri.com

But I cant understand why the header widget is not displaying on Google Chrome? Currently I tested only in IE, Firefox and Chrome and Chrome is not showing it at all.

Here is the code I used in the header.php file

`<div id="headerad">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-2') ) : ?> <?php endif; ?>
</div>`

And in functions.php file I used this:

```
function my_widgets_init() {
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Header Area', 'Focus' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-2',
    'description' => __( 'An optional widget area for your site header', 'your-theme' ),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="headwidget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</div>",
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
}
```

Please help me with this...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using AdBlock and forgetting to turn it off on this domain. It seems something in the header triggers it. Try refreshing the page without AdBlock.

Comment: Hey thanks so much :) It fixed the issue... I was wondering only something is wrong with the browser itself.